# Cosine similarity for a group of vectors

Tags: r, similarities

I am starting to work in R with the following case: 35 countries have scores between [0,1] in 120 dimensions and I need to show that there are differences in the way their scores distribute across these dimensions. For example, if there were 5 dimensions, (1,0.5,0,0,0) is different than (0,0,0,0.5,1). This is why I chose to use Cosine Similarity (CS) as a measure, since I am more worried about the "direction" rather than the intensity of their scores.

Since CS is a measure between individual vectors, I end up with a 35x35 matrix of values but my problem is that I still need to find an appropriate criteria/test to say if they are **all** similar or not. I'm uncertain if it would be correct to just say that if all values in the matrix are >0.95 then they are all similar. I'm also not very good with statistics, so forgive me if I said some nonsense.

Any advice?

PD: I also thought about seeing if data is actually clustered or not, i'm not sure.

Comment: Because cosine similarity is so closely related to (Pearson) correlation--it's essentially the same thing--you can find helpful information by researching ways to compare correlations.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use Fisher's transformation and compare correlations, but I dont know what to compare them with and how to know if it is significant. I also found an N-dimensional KS mehtod but dont know how to implement it (Fasano & Franceschini, 1987)

Comment: If you're not sure what to compare them with that means you're not sure what question you're asking, so let's start there: what is your research question?  What are you trying to learn?  What expectations do you have concerning your data?

Comment: The hypothesis to prove is: The score patterns are different among countries. Each dimension represents an independent category, there is no category better than other intrinsically so they are all equally valuable. My expectation would be to show that there are some countries (10%?) that have a significantly different pattern. Considering these two things is why I thought of a Kolmogorov Smirnov to see if I divide the countries into two random groups and compare them, then the test would show if they follow the same distribution or not.

Comment: (1) It appears that the cosine similarity does not entirely capture your sense of "difference" among patterns. (2) How these data are compared will depend on how the "scores" are measured or computed.  What do the raw data look like and how are scores derived from them?